# Scandir fails to open directory

Tags: php

```
$contentdirectory = '/dead-wave/dead-wave_content'; 

      $contentlaunch = scandir($contentdirectory);
```

that's what I'm using to create an array from which I echo it's values using a for each statement. this works perfectly on my dedicated server, but once hosted on godaddy servers returns an error message 'failed to open dir: No such file or directory in...' now the directory path is certainly correct the actual problem is unknown to me. Any Thoughts?

Comment: Your full directory path on the server is probably not `'/dead-wave/dead-wave_content'`, is it?

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct relative to the GoDaddy hosting server? I mean, is it a VPS or other dedicated server, or shared hosting? It might be something like `/usr/dead-wave/dead-wave_content` or something else . Do you have the correct permissions to list the directory contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure the path is correct? If the path is a subdirectory of your current directory, you should use 'dead-wave/dead-wave_content' instead of '/dead-wave/dead-wave_content'.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure the path is correct? on a hosting you are usually rooted to a different directory (like `/home/user1`).

So the Path from above would be `/home/user1/dead-wave/dead-wave_content/`

you can do a

```
exec('pwd',$return);
print_r($return);
```

to find out where you actually are.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the same problem you're having but sometimes I can't use any file i/o functions when I'm running *unit tests* on top of **Zend Server** via Zend Studio even though they worked on **Apache**.

I think you need to rewrite you paths somehow making them relative to the *server web directory* constant. I'm not sure what that is but I'm sure there is one.

**EDIT** Oh! **I don't think** Apache recognizes '/toplevel/secondlevel' path writing style.